# After update to 5.4, fopen can't read file

Tags: php, encryption

I have a website on a host that recently switched from PHP 5.2 to 5.4, and required us to chose a new php.ini file:  5.4 plain, 5.4 solo (just one php.ini file used throughout the site), and 5.4 fast.

I do not know which one I was using prior to making the switch, but when I did, (I chose 5.4 solo), I noticed that a part of my website that depends on mbstring (multibyte characters) no longer works.

In specific, it opens a text file that is full of characters and then that is used in an encryption script and it stores garbage in the mysql database.  Then to retrieve it, it's again run through the script and decrypted, and displayed on the screen.

This worked just fine until the 5.4 change.  Now it appears that it's unable to retrieve (open?) the text file.  I have tested this with a non-multibyte character version and that works fine, so I don't think the issue is with the code, but rather with the way PHP is treating multibyte chars...and I suspect, just a hunch, that this is fixable by tweaking the PHP.ini file somehow.  Zend.multibyte seems to be PHP's new thing.

My problem is that I have no idea what to tweak.  I tried several different Zend.multibyte/mbstring combos and that didn't work.

I know that everything works up until a string is sent for encryption.  It comes back as a null value, instead of a garbled string.  I feel like something in the string is being rejected by PHP and thus it's failing...offering nothing instead of the string it should.

Does anyone have a thought as to what might be happening and why my script no-longer works with 5.4?  I have checked and the mbstring module IS loaded, with default values in the php.ini.

Any suggestions would be great...I'm totally stumped.  Even some additional reports or ways to test or narrow down the problem would be fantastic.

Thank you!

Here is some code, where I think the problem is:

```
$this->s1 = "";

$s1array = array("a1.txt", "a2.txt", "a3.txt");


foreach ($s1array as $i => $value) {
            $myFile = "../a/dir/somewhere/$s1array[$i]";
            $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
            $theData = fgets($fh);
            fclose($fh);
            $this->s1 .= html_entity_decode($theData, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');    
}
```

The files ../a/dir/somewhere/a1.txt and ../a/dir/somewhere/a2.txt (etc) are semi-comma delimited strings of html coded letters, for example:  & #x0fb0f;& #x02c97;& #x00436;& #x10833;& #x00514; (I added the spaces so it would show code not the HTML values!).

But I guess now, for some reason, this above code isn't returning any results.  If I assign the result to a variable and echo that variable, there's nothing.  But if I assign $this->s1 = "abcde"; or a longer string and skip the "foreach" part, it will work.  So something in this process, this code, no longer works in 5.4. Can anyone tell what's going on here?  Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked the settings in your original php.ini file?

Comment: show some actual code. php wouldn't mangle a multi-byte string unless you somehow ran it ran it through non-multibyte-safe string operations.

Comment: The most obvious candidate to change PHP's behaviour when working with UTF-8 strings is [mbstring.func_overload](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php) which can switch functions like strlen(), strpos(), substr(), etc to work with character positions rather than byte positions

Comment: The security of your code should not depend on the confidentiality of the source, see [Kerckhoffs's Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle).

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestions!  I will investigate mbstring.func_overload asap.  Are there any recommended settings?  Since the multi-byte strings worked fine and the code _didn't change_ even a little bit, I feel like it's not the code.  Everything was working fine in multibyte before February where I clicked "upgrade to 5.4."  If there are any other php.ini type tweaks that might affect it, please let me know!

Comment: If anyone is still interested in this, I realized that the script works fine if I use Latin values such as "a" or "b."  But when I use "&#x00498;" "&#x02df7;"  (UTF-8?  Unicode?) values, the script fails.  Again, it used to work fine prior to 5.4 so is there some setting (maybe NOT in php.ini?!!) that tells PHP how to properly parse and recognize these values?  It _seems_ like it could be in the "mbstring" settings since that's where the internal encodings are set...but maybe elsewhere also needs to be changed?

Comment: I added some code lines after a bit of sleuthing.  It appears that this code isn't pulling out any value.  Just null.  Grrr.

Comment: This seems to work in all PHP versions 5.0+: http://3v4l.org/OWbrt. Can you try that simple code snippet as standalone script and see if that fails? Can you make sure you have error reporting on? Can you post any relevant parts of `phpinfo()`?

Comment: @deceze thank you for the helpful suggestions.  I will try these things and post results soon.

Comment: Is there any chance this change would affect permissions needed to access the file?  If I place a file in the same directory as the code, it seems to work.  If I do it "../some/dir/here/file" then it fails.  If there is a PHP.ini setting (or hosting setting?) that defaults to not allow this kind of recursive path maybe that's the problem?

Comment: (The perms are 644 for the "../some/dir/here/file" by the way...)

Comment: So, the problem appears to be solely in reading data from the file, not in converting the contents?

Comment: Yes, @deceze - It seems like the file reading issue is paramount to any UTF-8 issues.  (Pretty hard to have a UTF-8 issue if one has a NULL value where there should be input! Lol.)  It might be as "simple" as that but wth, I have no idea why it would suddenly not be able to read the file unless it was something to do with buffers or some kind of default in php.ini I needed to alter.  These are large files actually (Most of the known Unicode values!) but even my test on a small file is failing.

Comment: @deceze Okay, finally, a clue.  Seems like it IS something to do with the file contents after all.  I made a test file that's just Latin1 chars (aAbBcCdD, etc.) and it works fine in the same dir or the relative path.  But when I use a text file that's Unicode values (&#xOOO1;&#xOOOA,&#xOOOD, etc.) then we have the problem.  So it probably IS reading the file but something within it is causing it to fail.

Comment: One key thing is that my files contain almost all the known Unicode values, even ones that are non "printable" such as spaces, hardbreaking spaces, returns, and so on.  Could there be an issue in php.ini and the "replacement char" that's causing issues?  I still don't have an explanation for why it would work fine with the SAME FILE in the same dir, and NOT work if the file is moved up in the dir tree.  That's just totally baffling me.  But it does seem like a Latin1 char file has no problems and the Unicode encoded one does.  Annnny chance you have a clue why?

Comment: SAME HERE. Worked fine. Now doesn't work. I deleted all my code except for fopen(url,'r') and it stops right at this line. I tried all the other methods; CURL (Nope!); file_get_contents (Nope!). PHP Settings, "Allow URL" - yes has been enabled forever. Must be something deep, who really knows, the developers miss things sometimes (Oh deprecate deprecate deprecate obliterate...).

Answer (score 0):

Why you use fopen and so on for text files when you could use `file_put_contents` and `file_get_contents` - they are mostly wrappers for fopen, freads and so on. I have NEVER ever had any problems with UTF8 using that two functions.

Also make sure everything (from php, to db if you are using it, and php files) are encoded or using utf8. There is nothing funnier than *.php files in for example latin2 and all the rest in utf8.

Comment: Thank you @Seti for the help. I'm not using them simply because up to now they were working fine and I didn't (don't) want to really rewrite the code if it's not necessary. But it might be necessary. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: They are almost the same in speed, and also provide easier error reporting - when writing, it returns number of bytes written to the file. And so on. And i have never ever had any problems with utf8 or other encodings when i used them.